# Difficulty Understanding the Do-While Loop on C++

Tags: c++, do-while

I am a few weeks into programming in C++, and I am having a hard time understanding the Do-While Loop. Specifically, I do not understand this piece of code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;

int y = 0;

do

{

   for ( int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
         sum = sum + x;

   y = y+1;

} while ( y < 3);

cout << sum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

and its result:

```
30
```

I do not know how it resulted in 30, and it would be nice if I could get an explanation for this specific block of code. Thank you.

Comment: This program adds up numbers from 1 to 4, and repeats that three times. `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 == 10`, doing it three times results in 30.

Comment: Try running the program line by line in a debugger.

Comment: Why don't you try explaining to us what *you* think it does?  And maybe tell us what number you think the result should have been?

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger, printing the different values may help. [Like this](https://godbolt.org/z/5j1zr3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that, what I see, the the code goes into the do block, it sees the for loop, executes that loop 4 times, you then proceed to increment y, and then the process is done 2 more times.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int sum = 0;
    int y = 0;
    
    do {
        
        // the code sees this for loop and executes it 4 times
        for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
            sum = sum + x;
        
        y = y + 1; // you increment y by 1, then the code goes back up and repeats the process 2 more times
    } while (y < 3); // execute this block 3 times in total
    
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program does 10+10+10, because you write it so it does the sum of integer numbers smaller than 5.

And you said do it while y<3
which means it will do it for values from 0 to 2
so it does 1+2+3+4==10
for values 0,1,2 which is 3 times and give you the result of 30.

Answer (score 0):

`do ... while (cond)` loop works that way, that the condition `cond` is checked after first iteration of the loop (so it goes at least through one iteration). When you enter that loop first, you encounter `for` loop, which sums all integers in range from 1 to 4. The result of `sum` after first iteration of outer loop is 10 and value of `y` is now 1, so we move to the next iteration. Again we sum all numbers in inner loop and we add the result to the previous result of `sum` (which was 10), now the result is 20. We increment `y`, so it is 2, condition `y < 3` still holds, so we move to the next iteration. Again we sum numbers, `sum` is now 30 and we increment `y`, so it is 3. Condition of `do ... while` loop does not hold anymore, as `y` is now 3, which is not smaller than 3. At this moment `sum` is 30 and it gets printed on standard output.